# How do I create a CSV file from a model & then add it as an email attachment?

Tags: python, django, email, csv

I'm trying to generate a CSV from an object stored in my database and then add the csv to an email as an attachment.

I'm using Django 1.7 & Python 2.7.

I'm getting this error with the following code: "AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'encode'"

Here's my code:

```
def export_as_csv(report, fields, force_fields):
     print "export to csv started"
     """
    Generic csv export admin action.
    based on http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2020/
    extended for being able to give list_display as fields and work with     admin-defined functions
    """
    opts = report
    if not force_fields:
        field_names = set([field.name for field in opts.fields])
        if fields:
        fieldset = set(fields)
            field_names = field_names & fieldset
    elif fields:
        field_names = set(fields)
    else:
        raise("option force_fields can only be used in parallel with option fields")

    writer = csv.writer(open("myfile.csv","w"), delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    writer.writerow(list(field_names))
    row = []
    for field in field_names:
        try:
        row.append(unicode(getattr(report, field)).encode('utf-8'))
        except AttributeError:
            row.append(unicode((getattr(report, field)(report))).encode('utf-8'))
        except:
            raise
    writer.writerow(row)

    response = writer
    return response
```

The code below returns the above function's output as a parameter in mail.attach().
The report parameter is my DB model/object that's created & saved before any of this code is called.

```
list_display = ('primary_id', 'created_date', 'report_size',)
mail = EmailMessage('Email Subject', 'Email Body', None, ['example@example.com'])
mail.attach("report.csv", export_as_csv(report, fields = list_display, force_fields=True) , "text/csv")
mail.send()
```

Here's the model for a Report() object:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    primary_id = models.IntegerField('Primary Key', primary_key = True, default=0) 
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('Created date', default=timezone.now)
    report_size = models.IntegerField('Report Size', default=0)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's how I ideally want this code to work: export_as_csv() returns a CSV object that I don't need to save as a file or in my database - then the code attaches that to the email directly from a CSV object in memory, not a saved file.  Not sure if this is possible, but that's ideal for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csvwriter` can write to any object with a `write()` method, according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer). The usual Python class to use when you want an in-memory filelike object is a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) instance, or `cStringIO` if you're sure you won't be writing Unicode objects to it. So your `export_to_csv` function should look something like:

```
import cStringIO

def export_as_csv(report, fields, force_fields):
    # define field_names as above, assuming your indentation is correct
    csv_buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()        
    writer = csv.writer(csv_buffer, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    field_names = list(field_names) # loses order, but at least it's consistent
    writer.writerow(field_names)
    row = []
    for field in field_names:
        row.append(getattr(report, field).encode('utf-8'))
    writer.writerow(row)
    return csv_buffer
```

Then something like:

```
mail.attach("report.csv", export_as_csv(report, fields=list_display, force_fields=True).getvalue() , "text/csv")
```

Key differences are:

1) `csv_buffer` is an in-memory filelike object. Nothing is written to the file system.

2) This handles field lookup for the simple model fields `'primary_id', 'created_date', 'report_size'` that you show in your example code. If you actually need to handle the names of callables in your`field_names` sequence, it gets harder.

3) This uses a single variable to hold the `field_names` after converting to a list. It will probably work to use `list(field_names)` and `for field in field_names` while `field_names` is a set, Python sets and dictionaries should be order-stable as long as no modifications are made, but I find it clearer and more reliable to be explicit about making sure the order syncs up.

4) This returns the `cStringIO.StringIO` object rather than the writer. The writer's work is done once you've written everything you want to to it. The `cStringIO` object, conversely, should return the buffered CSV contents when you call `getvalue()` on it.